# I want to execute a JCL step no matter what the RC of previous step is?

Tags: conditional-statements, mainframe, jcl

There are 3 steps in my JCL:

STEP 1: process
STEP 2: NDM
STEP 3: DELETE OUTPUT after NDM

What I want to accomplish? 
I want to execute STEP 3 no matter what the return code of step 2 is.

I tried this: 
COND=(16,GT) and COND=(16,ST,STEP 2) but it's not doing what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try COND=EVEN on your final step’s EXEC statement.

From the documetnation:

> COND=EVEN tells MVS to execute this job step EVEN IF a prior  step in
>   the same job abends, unless the job is canceled by    the MVS
>   operator.

There's also a COND=ONLY:

> COND=ONLY tells MVS to execute this job step ONLY IF a prior  step in
>   the same job abends.

Explanation of COND:

COND is fairly counter-intuitive. The description is:

> If none of these tests is satisfied, the system executes the job step;
>   if any test is satisfied, the system skips the job step on which the
>   COND= parameter is coded.

So your COND=(16,GT) means "If 16 is greater than the return code from any previous steps, don't execute this step". So this step would only execute if ALL the previous steps finished with a RC > 16.

COND=(16,ST,STEP 2) is invalid - ST is not a valid condition. Valid tests are :

```
EQ - equal                    
LT - less than                
LE - less than or equal to    
NE - not equal                
GT - greater than             
GE - greater than or equal to
```

To make a step run, no matter what the condition codes from previous steps are, you could code COND=(0,GT), which means 'if 0 is greater than any previous return code (which it won't be), skip this step.'.

To be safe, you could code:

```
COND=((0,GT),EVEN)
```

as EVEN will cause this step to execute even if a previous step ABENDs.

Comment: I used COND=EVEN, it resolved my problem. Thanks a lot.
Just out of curiosity, what is wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 5):

Using `COND=EVEN` has the potential pitfall that the STEP will run even if the previous step ABENDS. Coding `COND=(0,GT,STEP2)` should allow the step to run but not if there is an ABEND.

Alternately you could use `IF/THEN/ELSE/ENDIF` coding.

e.g.

```
//STEP2 EXEC PGM=NDM
//IF STEP2.RC >= 0 THEN
//STEP3 EXEC PGM=???
//ENDIF
```

or

```
//STEP2 EXEC PGM=NDM
//IF STEP2.RC GE 0 THEN
//STEP3 EXEC PGM=???
//ENDIF
```

i.e. either `>=` or `GE` can be used.

You may find this helpful [IF/THEN/ELSE/ENDIF Statement Construct](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_1.13.0/com.ibm.zos.r13.ieab600/ifuse.htm#ifuse)

or for the COND parameter [COND Parameter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_1.13.0/com.ibm.zos.r13.ieab600/xexcond.htm)

Comment: I would follow Mikes advice and go for IF/THEN/ELSE statements. Condition codes are an anachronism that belong in the bad old day and should be avoided at all costs. That's my opinion anyway ;)

Comment: I second the above advice.

Comment: I third that advice.  IF/THEN/ELSE/ENDIF is significantly easier to maintain and understand.